# Send array with alphanumeric keys with Ajax to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I need to receive names of keys and values from alphanumeric array sended by ajax to php.

from this:

```
<input class="input" name="one" value="1" onchange="myFunction()">        
<input class="input" name="two" value="2" onchange="myFunction()">   
<input class="input" name="three" value="3" onchange="myFunction()">
```

which is parsed from loop

```
{% for x in y %}
   <input class="input" name="{{ x.k }}" value="{{ x.v }}" onchange="myFunction()">
{% endfor %}
```

I need to print_r() something like this:

```
Array
(
    ['one'] => 1,
    ['two'] => 2,
    ['three'] => 3,
)
```

if I'm doing this way:

```
 function myFunction() {
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
    var data = {};    
    var key = elementy[0].name;
    var value = elementy[0].value;
    data = { key: value};

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: {data:data} ,
    }); 
  }
```

print_r($data) return:

```
Array
(
    [key] => 1
)
```

if I'm doing this way:

```
function myFunction() {
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
    var data = {};    
    data = {elementy[0].name : elementy[0].value};

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: {data:data} ,
    });   
}
```

there is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` in this line `data = {elementy[0].name : elementy[0].value};`

I need to do something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var data = []; 
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < elementy.length; i++){ 
        data[elementy[i].name] = elementy[i].value;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('test') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {data:data}
    });   
}
```

but without syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `form` element surrounding the fields, the easiest way to do that would be to [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form:

```
data: $('form').serialize()
         ^^^^ if you have more forms, address it by its ID or something similar
```

If you don't have a form, you can also use:

```
data: $('.input').serialize()
```

as `serialize` can also be used to address selections of individual form controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_arr = $('input.input');
var data = [];
var i = 0;
input_arr.each(function(){
data[i] = {
    name:$(this).attr('name') ,
    value:$(this).val()
};
i++;
});
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
function myFunction() {
    var data = []; 
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < elementy.length; i++){ 
        data[elementy[i].name] = elementy[i].value;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('test') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {data:data}
    });   
}
```

should be

```
function myFunction() {
    var data = {}; 
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < elementy.length; i++){ 
        data[elementy[i].name] = elementy[i].value;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('test') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {data:data}
    });   
}
```